# ORDER A TEXT IN A COLUMN POWERQUERY

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to know if you can assist me in the following matter:

in PowerQuery I have a column like this:
input
[image: Example 1]

and i would like to Sort the column "CANAL / BU" like this:
[image: out example]

I tried to sort the function but sort the entire column not the text.

could you guys please so kind to assist me?

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, it appears you only want to sort the text in a single column.

You can do that by:

- Split each text line by the "/" into a List.
- Sort the List
- Recombine the List using the "/" delimiter.

A line of M Code that will do that:

```
    #"Sort Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step",
    {"CANAL/BU", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(Text.Split(_,"/")),"/")})
```

Of course, you could also do this by adding a custom column and sorting there; but with the `Table.TransformColumns` method, you don't need the extra column.

Here is code that will reproduce the first few columns of your table, and show the sorting step in situ:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords(
        {
            [AREA="Channel Marketing",
            #"CANAL/BU"="WT/NT/O",
            GPID=70181170]
        }
    ),
    #"Change Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"AREA", type text}, {"CANAL/BU", type text}, {"GPID", Int64.Type}}),

    #"Sort Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Change Type",
        {"CANAL/BU", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(Text.Split(_,"/")),"/")})

in
    #"Sort Column"
```

***Output***
[image]

Comment: thank you so much, it worked and applied the code.